How to pull a list of emails from an Excel file and send one email to that list?
Basically, I have this excel file that will have a column called "Email" that will list people's emails. I'd like to be able to use Power Automate to extract the email addresses of folks based on certain criteria and send one email to that group in Outlook. So, if there are five people who are signed up for a session on October 5th, they'd receive one email. Basically, I'm trying to send a mass email to folks who are signed up for specific sessions.
I know I have to use the "list rows in table" action in Power Automate, but I'm struggling with how to pull all the emails and not have them in an "apply to each." I need some way to be able to join the extracted emails with a semi colon and then have that output be entered into the "to" line in send an Outlook Email action. What would I need to do to get the emails to be formatted in this way?

You can try using the JOIN option

@AkhilSuthapalli, so I would join the outputs from the apply to each?

Here is my compiled output
input table inside a worksheet. Select all emails with event "1"

Full flow:



Use List rows present in a table action and give the location of the excel file. It will import the data
Initialize a variable - array called emails
Initialize another variable - String called emailsFinal
Use Select like this (ignore spelling mistake in pictures)

this will create a dictionary from the row iterations
Add a condition for iteration. The moment you add Parse JSON and select the output of Select action the loop is created
Now we need to parse the JSON taking current item as input and describe the schema for the earlier created Select output.
Once we have the data parsed, we can use to validate the condition like this

If the condition is true (the event value is 1) then we append the value to variable emails
once out of the loop we need to make a string use JOIN with from field as emails and join with field as ;. this will result in a string of all email address.
Set the Output of the JOIN to emailsFinal
I used a notification to retrieve the text, you can use in the to field of Outlook

Here is a snapshot of emails from my notification bar


Hey @akhil, we can't get the select outside of an apply to each If we select from the value or body. Any ideas?

i suggest start from beginning, use select and give the param. try to run the flow once so that the table data is fetched which will be useful for further compilation.
